# creating  a dynamic menu in wordpress

Tags: menus, multisite

I'm trying to use the dynamic menu of wordpress! So I try to create an dropdown based on category, my question is... I need to block the first (title/category name) for being access .... right now it will take a page with all post of that category, I only need to display the categories in the menu but users cannot click on it!!

Do you guys know which function I should use in order to do that?

Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a # for the URL in a Custom Links item and then the menu item will not link anywhere, but can be used for a top menu item. See http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide